# Restored container from the docker image oracle db, can not connect

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle11g

I reinstalled the operating system and therefore it was necessary to transfer the docker container oracle 11g database. Made an export this way:

```
docker commit e198aac7112d export/server1:tag1

docker save export/server1 > export_server1.tar.gz
```

and then restored and launched it

```
docker load < export_server1.tar.gz

sudo docker run e198aac7112d
```

and now I can’t join it, I enter a username and password and I get an error:

```
[08006] [17002] IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check container network?

Comment: @Sachith Muhandiram I want to connect the container locally, on the same machine, if you mean it?

Comment: did you check `netstat -tnlp`